# What's the cmd line equivalent of "ls -a" in Powershell on Windows Vscode?

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I want a to display *all* files (including hidden ones) on a directory in Powershell opened in Windows VS Code. I want the Powershell equivalent of 'ls -a'.

How do I do that?

I've tried:

```
dir ./d
dir /a
dir ./a
dir /ad
dir \h
```

...and many variations of these

Comment: Was `dir /a` one of your variations? If yes, what's wrong with it?

Comment: thanks, @Stephan. the error was "Cannot find path 'C:\a' because it does not exist"

Comment: it probably has something to do with me using the vscode terminal

Comment: Technically, as your question is for displaying **all files**, the appropriate command would use ```/A:-D /B```. Without `:-D` it would include directories, and without `/B` it would include additional file information too.

Comment: Well, it's not `dir ./a`, but `dir /a`

Comment: @JeffRSon thanks. that was onoe of the variations i tried. I think the error has to do with me using the vscode command terminal

Comment: So if you had quoted the *whole* error message it could be seen that it's not cmd but Powershell. In PowerShell the command would be `get-childitem -force`

Comment: @JeffRSon my bad. you're right. it worked. if oyu want to, you can post that in an answer format. I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: As your question is not about `cmd.exe`, but about `powershell.exe`, you should not have added that information to the question, especially without modifying the question tags, because you've already received multiple answers and comments for `cmd.exe`. What you should have done was make an apology for your mistake in the question area, and submit a new question. In any case, what you could have done was use: ```ls -af -fo```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command in cmd to list all files (and directories) is `dir /a`.

PowerShell, on the other hand, has an alias named "dir" (obviously confusing) which actually calls the cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` which works different. `dir /a` in PowerShell would report an error:

> "Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\a' because it does not exist."

In order to see all files in PowerShell you would use either of

```
Get-ChildItem -Force
dir -Force
```

So which command to use in the end depends on your shell or terminal (with default or chosen shell).

Comment: `ls` is also aliased in powrshell so `ls -force` is equivalent to to `ls -a` if one is used to linux commands

Answer (score 0):

`dir /a /b .` is the syntax.

```
C:\tmp>dir /a /b .
hid
hidsys
nrm
sys

C:\tmp>attrib
A   H        C:\tmp\hid
A  SH        C:\tmp\hidsys
A            C:\tmp\nrm
A  S         C:\tmp\sys
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

`dir /s /b /o:gn`

/s - displays all files in the specific directory + subdirectories.

/b - strips heading information and summary from the output.

/o - sort the files in the list, followed by :gn - **g** sorts first folders, then files. **n** puts them in alphabetical order.

Comment: doesn't include hidden or system files.